# Getting System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException, while using Accord Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, accord.net

I'm getting `System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException` with "External component has thrown an exception" message, while trying to create avi file with Accord Framework by calling `writer.Open("test.avi", width, height, 25, VideoCodec.MPEG4);`

Here is my code snippet:

```
    public class Recording
{
    int width = 320;
    int height = 240;

    int framesCountTest = 0;

    // create instance of video writer
    VideoFileWriter writer = new VideoFileWriter();

    public Recording()
    {
        try
        {
            // create new video file, , Here I'm getting the exception
            writer.Open("test.avi", width, height, 25, VideoCodec.MPEG4);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void WriteFrameToFile(Bitmap image)
    {
        if (framesCountTest >= 60) return;

        // create a bitmap to save into the video file
        image = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        writer.WriteVideoFrame(image);

        framesCountTest++;
        if (framesCountTest >= 60) { writer.Close(); }
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
        StackTrace  "   at sws_getContext(Int32 , Int32 , PixelFormat , Int32 , Int32 , PixelFormat , Int32 , SwsFilter* , SwsFilter* , Double* )\r\n   at Accord.Video.FFMPEG.?A0x9c42894c.open_video(WriterPrivateData data)\r\n   at Accord.Video.FFMPEG.VideoFileWriter.Open(String fileName, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 frameRate, VideoCodec codec, Int32 bitRate, AudioCodec audioCodec, Int32 audioBitrate, Int32 sampleRate, Int32 channels)\r\n   at Accord.Video.FFMPEG.VideoFileWriter.Open(String fileName, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 frameRate, VideoCodec codec)\r\n   at ELSY.Core.Streaming.Recording..ctor() in C:\\Users\\ustr\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\TestVid\\H3\\Core.Stream\\Recording.cs:line 107"   string
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues/345 this should have been fixed some releases ago. If it is not the case, I think you may want to re-open that issue. Sorry for any inconveniences this issue might have caused.

Comment: I got rid of this exception by removing writer.Open() method from constructor and placing it in some method.